# Bit manipulation (python vs solidity)

Tags: solidity, python, bytes

I am working on translating code from Python to Solidity and everything has worked up until this last loop. Cannot figure out where the difference is in the code (besides the bytes being in decimal and hex encodings). Follows is the code in both languages and the outputs.

Python

```
outmasks = bytes([12, 11, 12, 14, 23, 8, 9, 9, 7, 3, 6, 5, 19, 19, 6, 6, 4, 6, 6, 0, 9, 6, 13, 14, 19, 2, 7, 4, 0, 0, 0, 12, 23, 8, 8, 10, 6, 14, 14, 9, 4, 5, 6, 5, 20, 11, 12, 11])

for cnt in range(0x30):
    outs |= outmasks[cnt] << 5*cnt

print(hex(outs))
```

`0x5b174298a44b9c6521176000021c53734c9018c431a73298674a5177316c`

Solidity

```
function test() public returns (bytes30 outs) {

    bytes memory outmasks = hex"0c0b0c0e1708090907030605131306060406060009060d0e130207040000000c1708080a060e0e0904050605140b0c0b";


    for (uint8 cnt = 0; cnt<48; cnt++) {
        outs |= outmasks[cnt] << 5*cnt;
    }
}
```

`0x6c0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I came up with:

```
 function test() public returns (bytes30 outs) {

     bytes memory outmasks = hex"0c0b0c0e1708090907030605131306060406060009060d0e130207040000000c1708080a060e0e0904050605140b0c0b";

     for (uint8 cnt = 0; cnt<47; cnt++) {
         outs |= bytes30(outmasks[cnt]) >> (232 - 5 *cnt);
     }
     outs |= bytes30(outmasks[47]) << 3;
 }
```

The question would be now: WHY?

Your solution takes a byte from the outmask array. What you get is a **byte** value! We have 2 cases now:

- `cnt < 2`: You shift within the byte range
- `cnt >= 2`: You shift your value out of the byte range. That results in `outmasks[cnt] << 5*cnt = 0x00`

That is the reason why you get `0x6c0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000`

---

Now here is something I find very odd and can't explain why Solidity is doing that.

If you cast byte to byte30 it sets the value as MSB. (for example: `0x30 -> 0x300000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000`). That is the reason why I have the right shift, instead of the left shift.

---

I hope you are able to follow it. I made it in a rush. Sorry

Comment: It is how padding works in solidity, `bytesXX` will pad to the left, and `uintXX` will pad to the right, ie `bytes2(bytes1(0xFF)) -> 0xFF00` and `uint16(uint8(0xFF)) -> 0x00FF`.

Comment: So it is a Solidity think?

Comment: Yes, it is a convention of Solidity. All data at the EVM level are 32 bytes.